# Why does aptitude refrain from upgrading [UNAVAILABLE] packages?

Tags: ubuntu, aptitude

Why does aptitude refrain from upgrading in the example below? Is it solely because existing package metadata is not in cache anymore? If package is marked as `[UNAVAILABLE]`, does it mean the only sensible action is to keep it?

```
system-config-printer-common will not be upgraded to version
1.4.2+20130920-0ubuntu1.2, to avoid breaking the following dependencies:

  * system-config-printer-common replaces system-config-printer [UNAVAILABLE]
  * system-config-printer-common replaces system-config-printer-gnome (<
    1.3.11+20120807-0ubuntu7) [UNAVAILABLE]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is why `apt-get` is now recommended over `aptitude` for system upgrades.  In this case, `aptitude` doesn't know how to proceed with the now obsolete package `system-config-printer`.  It no longer exists but other things still depend on it.  Various install guides suggest removing certain packages, force installing others, and/or forcing breakages to occur that will get cleaned up manually in further steps.

(I've not run into such a mess, personally, so I don't know what your best path forward may be. Using `apt-get` instead may get past this.)